# Using panels inside of tab-content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, panel

I'm using panels inside of tab-content.  e.g.

```
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="general" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="general-tab">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="interfaces" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="interfaces-tab">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            ...
```

The (non-panel) code was copied from an example at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

The problem I have is that when the "interfaces" tab is selected, its panels are displayed in positions which take account of the now-invisible "general" tab's panels.

How can I get each tab-pane to be laid-out without leaving spaces for invisible panes from other tabs?

Comment: Ok, I don't really understand the question. Can you post a complete, minimal examplee?

Comment: @Zim After looking at the source for the supposedly bootstrap-4 template, it turns out it's using bootstrap 3!